# TYPO3 pass Fluid variable value to the Javascript

Tags: javascript, typo3, fluid, view-templates

In a fluid template I have a fluid variable which value I would like to use in my JavaScript code.

I am using JavaScript inside of fluid template.

My Code:

```
<!-- value I would use further in my javascript -->
<h1 id="product-model">{product.model}</h1>

<!-- Javascript code (in the same file) -->
<script>
   <![CDATA[
     function printProductWindow() {
       document.title = document.getElementById("product");
       window.print(); 
     } 
   ]]>
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!
Denis

Comment: What is your Question??

Comment: Sorry if I wasn´t clear,

At the moment document.title has zero value, although {product.model} variable contains a value.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here....

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your element id is wrong:

```
 document.title = document.getElementById("product-model");
```

because you have defined it as `id="product-model"`.

Alternative, if your JavaScript is in your FluidTemplate, you can also set the Value there:

```
<script>
  <![CDATA[
    function printProductWindow() {
      document.title = "]]>{product.model}<![CDATA[";
      window.print(); 
    } 
  ]]>
</script>
```

But let me warn you: changing the title via JavaScript is not a good practice.

Have an look at the TitleTagViewHelper from the news extension [here](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/TitleTagViewHelper.php) to see one solution how this can be solved.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much :)

Comment: does not work anymore. Since TYPO3 8 <![CDATA[ blocks the output so the javascript is empty.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
        function printProductWindow() {
            document.title = <f:format.raw>{product.model}<f:format.raw>;
            window.print(); 
        }
</script>
```

> For TYPO3 8.7.

Comment: Apostrophes are missing "<f:format.raw>{product.model}<f:format.raw>"

Comment: I would suggest `<f:format.json>{product.model}</f:format.json>` to avoid XSS if `model` contain quotes

Comment: what If my JS is not in the same file as the template?

Comment: @LenonTolfo : Set the value as hidden in the template and fetch the value in any file ;)

Answer (score 4):

you can use the fluid variables in js as well but most of the time you need to use a format viewhelper like `<f:format.htmlspecialchars>`.

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[
        function printProductWindow() {
            document.title = '<f:format.htmlspecialchars>{product.model}</f:format.htmlspecialchars>';
            window.print(); 
        }
    ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnt work, but was pretty close... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ThingsToKnow/JsAndInline.html

```
<f:format.cdata>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var myLayout;
      $(document).ready(function() {
         myLayout = $('body').layout({
            north__size: 27,
            north__initClosed: false,
            north__initHidden: false,
            center__maskContents: true // IMPORTANT - enable iframe masking
         });
      });
   </script>
</f:format.cdata>
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your codeß

Comment: does not work anymore (since TYPO3 9.x). The curly brackets are now interpreted by fluid which ends up in complete messed up javascript. The manual is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
<!-- value I would use further in my javascript -->
<h1>{product.model}</h1>

<!-- Javascript code (in the same file) -->
<script>
     function printProductWindow() {
       <f:format.raw>
       document.title = {product.model};
       window.print(); 
       </f:format.raw>
     } 
</script>
```

Put the Viewhelper <f:format.raw> to the closest curly brackets which shoul output a variable to get the fluid detection right.